# Tkinter - Clicking on a word and adding to list removes previously added word

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a program in which when the user clicks a word in a textbox (in Tkinter) the word will be added to an arrayy/list. So far, the word gets added to the list but each time I click a new word the word that I previously clicked is removed. Below is my code

```
  def _on_click(self, event):
                search=[]    
                wordclicked=ArticleTextBox.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
                Search.append(wordclicked)
                print(Search)
```

Any help?

Comment: When you say it will "add it to an arrayy/list [sic]", which array are you talking about? You explicitly create one called `search`, and then you append to what we can only assume is a list named `Search`. Please create a [mcve], there's not enough detail in what you provided.

Comment: use global variable and don't assign empty list inside function.

Comment: Updated Title as requested in comments

Answer (score 0):

You have to create global variable or class variable `self.search` - now you create local variable and you assign empty list every time you click

```
def __init__(self):
   self.search = []

def _on_click(self, event):
   wordclicked = ArticleTextBox.get("insert wordstart", "insert wordend")
   self.search.append(wordclicked)
   print(self.search)
```